# WLAN setup for campus

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I need to setup WLAN in a college campus with around 200m radius.

The main Router is in Library.

What I need is to provide Wi-Fi access in each department including library and Auditorium.

SSID should be one or multiple, depending on future use.

This is my first networking related work. So please ignore my little knowledge.

will
i. [Ubiquiti PicoStation M2HP 2.4GHz 802.11g/n High Power Access Point](http://dl.ubnt.com/datasheets/picostationm/picom2hp_DS.pdf) be a good option if I place it in between Library and Auditorium.

ii. or shall I go for omni directional antenna ?

or is there a better way to do this?

[image: Site Diagram]

Comment: Multiple M2HP's, connected to the same wired network and configured with the same SSID, might be more reliable.

Comment: by multiple M2HP's you mean for each building one M2HP or just randomly 2-3 M2HP's?

Answer (score 0):

first check the signal meter strengh of your access point ,,, at this scale i thing you can better you use multi access point ( many company sad we support a strengh for example 200 meter but you must test it ,,, vendor always say lire to customer  in many reall strengh product ... you can use multi access point and config they for connect together

and in many company using roaming system on the wireless for accounting personel connect to internet